# jquery hide()/show() animation is repeating continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pretty new to jquery so I am facing some problems.I am trying to create a HTML in which if a user hover the mouse over a div component then a list is shown.But the problem is that if I move my mouse over the div then the list appears and disappears repeatedly.Thanks for helping me in advance.

Here is my html code:-

```js
$(function(){
 var det={
  firstname:'Gunjan',
  lastname:'Dutta Bhowmick'

 };
 $('ul').hide();
 $('ul').css({
  'background-color':'blue',
  'border':'2px solid green'
  
  
 });
 $('li').css({
  'color':'red'
 });
 $('div div').mouseover(function(){
  var id ='#'+$(this).attr('id')+' ul';
  
  $(id).fadeIn();
 
 }).mouseout(function(){
  var id ='#'+$(this).attr('id')+' ul';
  $(id).fadeOut();
  
 });
 $('html').dblclick(function(){
  alert(det.firstname+" "+det.lastname);

 });


});
```

```css
.features{
width: 1200px;
height: 90px;
margin-top:5px;
}
#Hobbs{
 width: 300px;
 height: 90px;

 background: green;
 display: inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top: 10px;

}
#Lang{
 width: 300px;
 height: 90px;
 background: red;
display: inline-block;
position:absolute;
top: 10px;
left:310px;

}
#Fri{
 width: 300px;
 height: 90px;
 background: yellow;
 display: inline-block;
position:absolute;
top: 10px;
left:610px;

}
li{
 color: green;
  width: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}
p{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <title>SimpleNav</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
<script  src="../jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>

 <script src="main.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="features">
 <div id="Hobbs">
  <p>Hobbies</p>
  <ul class="hlist">
   <li>Programming</li>
   <li>Playing Games</li>
   <li>Listening Music</li>
   <li>Playing Outdoor Games</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
  <div id="Lang">
   <p>Language</p>
   <ul class="llist">
    <li>JAVA</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
    <li>HTML</li>
    <li>JQUERY</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Fri">
  <p>Friends</p>
   <ul class="frlist">
    <li>Rohan</li>
    <li>Prithwish</li>
    <li>Souparna</li>
    <li>Priyo</li>
    <li>Sayantan</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) instead of [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout)

```js
$(function() {
  var det = {
    firstname: 'Gunjan',
    lastname: 'Dutta Bhowmick'

  };
  $('ul').hide();
  $('ul').css({
    'background-color': 'blue',
    'border': '2px solid green'


  });
  $('li').css({
    'color': 'red'
  });
  $('div div').mouseenter(function() {
    $('ul', this).stop().fadeIn();

  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $('ul', this).stop().fadeOut();

  });
  $('html').dblclick(function() {
    alert(det.firstname + " " + det.lastname);

  });


});
```

```css
.features {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#Hobbs {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
#Lang {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 310px;
}
#Fri {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 610px;
}
li {
  color: green;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="features">
  <div id="Hobbs">
    <p>Hobbies</p>
    <ul class="hlist">
      <li>Programming</li>
      <li>Playing Games</li>
      <li>Listening Music</li>
      <li>Playing Outdoor Games</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Lang">
    <p>Language</p>
    <ul class="llist">
      <li>JAVA</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>JQUERY</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Fri">
    <p>Friends</p>
    <ul class="frlist">
      <li>Rohan</li>
      <li>Prithwish</li>
      <li>Souparna</li>
      <li>Priyo</li>
      <li>Sayantan</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use the shorthand version provided by jQuery [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover)

```
$('div div').hover(function () {
    $('ul', this).stop().fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $('ul', this).stop().fadeOut();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var det = {
    firstname: 'Gunjan',
    lastname: 'Dutta Bhowmick'

  };
  $('ul').hide();
  $('ul').css({
    'background-color': 'blue',
    'border': '2px solid green'


  });
  $('li').css({
    'color': 'red'
  });
  $('div div').hover(function() {
    $('ul', this).stop().fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $('ul', this).stop().fadeOut();
  });
  $('html').dblclick(function() {
    alert(det.firstname + " " + det.lastname);

  });


});
```

```css
.features {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#Hobbs {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
#Lang {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 310px;
}
#Fri {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 610px;
}
li {
  color: green;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="features">
  <div id="Hobbs">
    <p>Hobbies</p>
    <ul class="hlist">
      <li>Programming</li>
      <li>Playing Games</li>
      <li>Listening Music</li>
      <li>Playing Outdoor Games</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Lang">
    <p>Language</p>
    <ul class="llist">
      <li>JAVA</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
      <li>HTML</li>
      <li>JQUERY</li>
      <li>CSS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="Fri">
    <p>Friends</p>
    <ul class="frlist">
      <li>Rohan</li>
      <li>Prithwish</li>
      <li>Souparna</li>
      <li>Priyo</li>
      <li>Sayantan</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir please can you explain why my code is showing such fault?Thank you very much for your immediate answer.

Comment: @Gunjan it is because the mouseover and mouseout event bubbles from descendant to ancestor elements....

Comment: But sir why will it hide and show the element continuously when I am keeping the mouse cursor on that specific div.I am not assigning any event to the external div.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function. You can try the `on` method

```
$('div div').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            // Handle mouseenter...
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            // Handle mouseleave...
        }
    });
```

You can get more about `on` method here [jQuery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)